# In the Encrypt module, can I switch between phpseclib and mcrypt assuming I keep the Key Provider Settings in place?

Tags: theming

A client uses the encrypt module as the basis to encrypt some database cells. The current server is RHEL 6/PHP 5.3. They're upgrading to RHEL 7 but will push to PHP 5.6.

The [Encrypt module](https://www.drupal.org/project/encrypt) asks for either a method:

- PHP Secure Communications Library (phpseclib)
- Mcrypt AES (CBC Mode)
- None

Currently the client had the second choice selected. However, the `php-mcrypt` package doesn't exist in PHP 5.6, and from my understanding, it itself hasn't been updated in a while. The alternative of installing the Libraries Module and cloning down a copy of `phpseclib` from `git clone https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib.git` seems more palatable at the moment.

**Question**: can I switch out to using `phpseclib` assuming I keep the Key Provider Settings in place?

[image]

Comment: Doubt it, if you're asking can you switch mid stream between one encrypt method and another, the answer is no.  You could upgrade/migrate the encryption.  Query the details, decrypt with old method, encrypt with new method, update records.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot just switch out the encryption methods. **Mcrypt AES (CBC Mode)** pads the input and also prepends two salts and an IV as well other information like the HMAC for authentication in it's output. `phpseclib` does none of this. Here are some examples:

```
encrypt('all your base');
// $text = "TUsE3Fwzvj6MT41ritVO/zUuJ/qWNmZJIBU3euDEX9iDMb3IqMyTJEFwssW/SI/GZ8ce/HxqrqPFWGzTNC0d7UZUtRjr2JReoqaCqw18GHyGhbjqr1zZbr/MCIT1rENM";

encrypt('all your base', array(), 'phpseclib');
// $text = "1r/WWYiCW9icZ93iUxStMQ==";
```

You can actually rewrite the existing `mcrypt` plugin to use `phpseclib` instead. You wouldn't necessarily need the HMAC stuff—it's there for added benefit but you can just skip it. But you likely could make a pain-free transition.

For example, replacing the existing decryption code in `_encrypt_encryption_methods_mcrypt_aes_cbc()`:

```
// Initialize for decryption.
mcrypt_generic_init($mcrypt, $ekey, $iv);

// Decrypt the data.
$processed_text = mdecrypt_generic($mcrypt, $text);

// Terminate decryption.
mcrypt_generic_deinit($mcrypt);

// Remove any padding.
$pad = ord($processed_text[strlen($processed_text) - 1]);
$processed_text = substr($processed_text, 0, -$pad);

// Close the Mcrypt handle.
mcrypt_module_close($mcrypt);
```

With this rewrite:

```
$path = libraries_get_path('phpseclib');
require_once $path . '/Crypt/AES.php';
$aes = new Crypt_AES();
$aes->setIV($iv);
$aes->setKey($ekey);
$processed_text = $aes->decrypt($text);
```

Returns the correct plain-text given the original `mcrypt` encryption ciphertext. At least, it should. I've got `mcrypt` on my system and so `phpseclib` is probably using it, but it should "just work" for you.

Oh yeah, FYI, use `phpseclib` 1.x. As the 2.x branch will not work.

Comment: I tested the above using Acquia DevDesktop using PHP 5.6.19 and phpseclib 1.0.5.